# Incorrect time records value from the ActiveCollab API

Tags: php, api, sdk, activecollab

I have a issue with the the output of the API.

I'm trying to build a system where I've integrated ActiveCollab and trying to fetch tasks and tasks related time records. All works fine but there is inconsistency in the time record values.

Please see the screenshot below:

https://prnt.sc/wfr5ak

In the above screenshot the time tracked values are `0.10` and `0.26` respectively.

Upon fetching the time records via the API with endpoint `/projects/1/tasks/1/time-records`, the values are different. The screenshot for the response array is attached below:

https://prnt.sc/wfuo14

The above screenshot have values `0.17` and `0.46` respectively which is completely wrong!

I'm not sure why that is happening? Can you guys let me know if I'm doing anything wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveCollab interface shows data in HH:MM format. API returns values in decimal format, as number of hours. For example, `1.5` in API is `1:30` in interface. Both values mean the same thing - one and a half hour.

Decimal format is returned because it allows easier calculation. It's also the format in which ActiveCollab stores tracked time values.

Comment: Yeah spot on! got it sorted now.